# Find the general solution of $y''+y'−6y=\alpha e^{rt}$ where $α$ and $r$ are constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of $$y''+y'−6y=\alpha e^{rt},$$ where $\alpha$ and $r$ are constants.

---

Struggling with the particular solution, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $r\ne2$ and $r\neq-3$ then let $y=Ae^{rt}$ and find $A$ by substuting in the DE, otherwise let $y=Ate^{rt}$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

1. Solve the homogeneous equation, assuming a solution of the form $y=e^{at}$, which yields $a^2+a-6=0$.
2. Pick a particular solution of the RHS, which should be $Ae^{rt}$ if $r$ does not solve the above equation, otherwise, $Ate^{rt}$, and plug in to find $A$.
3. Combine the solutions, by adding the homogeneous and inhomogeneous together.

Answer (score 0):

$$y′′+y′−6y=αe^{rt}\implies (D^2+D-6)y=αe^{rt}$$

Complementary finction (C.F.) is $\quad Ae^{2t}+Be^{-3t}\quad$where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

Now particular integral (P.I.)$=\frac{1}{D^2+D-6} αe^{rt}$
$=\frac{αe^{rt}}{r^2+r-6}$

---

> Consider a differential equation of the form $f(D)y=X$
>
> If $X=e^{ax}$, then
>
> $1.$ P.I.$\quad = \frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}}{f(a)}$, if $f(a)\neq 0$
>
> $2.$ P.I.$\quad =\frac{1}{(D-a)^n}e^{ax}=\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{ax}$